# Random number with biases

Tags: c++, random, numbers

So I have a map< int, float> containing the biases of numbers 1 - 6. I need to return a value that is biased. Take note that the biases are not constant as they are inputted by the user. It is in a class so all variables are already declared.

So this is what I've done so far.

```
    int die:: randomNumber(map < int, float >  &biasPercent)
    {
       randomString[0] << biasPercent[0];
       randomArray[0] = randomString[0].str();
       maximum = randomArray[0].size();

       for(counter = 0; counter < 6; counter++)
       {
          randomString[counter] << biasPercent[counter];
          randomArray[counter] = randomString[counter].str();

          if(randomArray[counter].size() > maximum)
          {
             maximum = randomArray[counter].size();
          }
       }

       limit = 1;



       for(counter = 1; counter <= maximum - 2; counter++)
       {
           limit *= 10;
       } 

       srand(time(NULL));

       random1 = rand() % limit + 1;

       if(random1 <= biasPercent[0] * limit)
       {
           return 1;
       }

       else if(random1 > biasPercent[0] * limit && random1 <= (biasPercent[0] * limit) + (biasPercent[1] * limit))
       {
           return 2;
       }

       else if(random1 > ((biasPercent[0] * limit) + (biasPercent[1] * limit) * limit) && random1 <= (((biasPercent[0] * limit) + (biasPercent[1] * limit)) + (biasPercent[2] * limit)))
       {
           return 3;
       }

       else if(random1 > (((biasPercent[0] * limit) + (biasPercent[1] * limit)) + (biasPercent[2] * limit)) && random1 <= (((((biasPercent[0] * limit) + (biasPercent[1] * limit)) + (biasPercent[2] * limit))) + (biasPercent[3] * limit)))
       {
          return 4;
       }

       else if(random1 > (((((biasPercent[0] * limit) + (biasPercent[1] * limit)) + (biasPercent[2] * limit))) + (biasPercent[3] * limit)) && random1 <= ((((((biasPercent[0] * limit) + (biasPercent[1] * limit)) + (biasPercent[2] * limit))) + (biasPercent[3] * limit))) + ((biasPercent[4] * limit)))
       {
          return 5;
       }

       else
       {
          return 6;
       }
    }
```

It doesn't seem to work as it only returns 1 all the time. I'm guessing that stringstream has something to do with that. But I don't know any other way how to know the limit of the random numbers than by converting the float to string then getting the value with the most characters. Please help.

Comment: C++ has a better random library `<random>` with explicit support for non-uniform distributions. Now you'd need to write your own distribution, since it's particular to your case, but that only needs to cover the distribution part - not the random number generation part.

Comment: Calling `srand` before you generate every number isn't helping.  If you stick with `rand` then call `srand` once at the beginning of your program.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution would be to calculate the `partial_sum` of all biases. The last element is the sum of biases. Now generate a random number with value [0, sum] (using `uniform_real_distribution`), and find the index of the `upper_bound` in your partial_sum.

E.g. biases [0.2, 0.5, 6, 2, 3, 0.1] give partial_sum [0.2, 0.7, 6.7, 8.7, 11.7, 11.8] so generate a number between 0 and 11.8. Say that's 4.378, the upper bound is 6.7 (third element) and the result therefore is 3.